# How do I output a compiled file from TXT text to the screen?

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment about "CaesarCipher". This assignment requires me to:
Write a program that will ask the user to enter the name of a file. Your program should then ask the user to enter 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'.
If the user enters anything else your program should print an error message and exit.
If they entered 'encrypt' your program should open the file and encrypt it by shifting each character (including white space) 3 values to the right.
If they entered 'decrypt' your program should open the file and decrypt it by shifting each character (including white space) 3 values to the left.

If the file fails to open your program should print an error message and exit.

The decrypted or encrypted message should be displayed on The screen and also written to an output file named "message".
Also report the frequency of the vowels (A ,E ,I , O, U, Y) in input message.

I think I'm more than halfway there, but I have no way to print the processed "c" value to the screen, and every time I try to run it I skip the middle part of the compiled text I want and print.

```
int main(){

    //Data Abstraction
    bool goodFile = true;
    bool goodCommand = true;
    string fileName;
    string command;
    string message;
    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream outputFile;
    int shift = 3;
    int numA = 0, numE = 0, numI = 0, numO = 0, numU = 0;
    char c;


    // Input
    cout << "Enter File Name: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << fileName << endl;
    cout << "Enter encrypt or decrypt: ";
    cin >> command;
    cout << command << endl;

    // Open File
    inputFile.open(fileName);
    outputFile.open(message);

    // Identify whether output Error message
    if(!inputFile){
            goodFile = false;
    }
    if(command != "encrypt" && command != "decrypt"){
            goodCommand = false;
    }
    if (goodCommand != true){
        cout << "Error: Bad Command." << endl;
    }
    if(goodFile != true){
        cout << "Error: File did NOT open." << endl;
    }

    // Identify process data or not

    if (goodFile == true && goodCommand == true){
            
            if(command == "decrypt"){
                shift = -3;
        }
            while(inputFile.get(c)){
                c+= shift;
                c = static_cast<char>(c+shift);
                cout << c;
                switch(toupper(c)){
                    case 'a':
                    break;
                    case 'e':
                    break;
                    case 'i':
                    break;
                    case 'o':
                    break;
                    case 'u':
                    break;
                }
            if(c == 'a'){
                numA++;
            }
            if(c == 'e'){
                numE++;
            }
            if(c == 'i'){
                numI++;
            }
            if(c == 'o'){
                numO++;
            }
            if(c == 'u'){
                numU++;
            }
        }
        outputFile << c << endl;
        outputFile << "Letter Frequency" << endl;
        outputFile << "   A    "<< numA << endl;
        outputFile << "   E    "<< numE << endl;
        outputFile << "   I    "<< numI << endl;
        outputFile << "   O    "<< numO << endl;
        outputFile << "   U    "<< numU << endl;
        inputFile.close();
        outputFile.close();

        cout << "Letter Frequency" << endl;
        cout << "   A    "<< numA << endl;
        cout << "   E    "<< numE << endl;
        cout << "   I    "<< numI << endl;
        cout << "   O    "<< numO << endl;
        cout << "   U    "<< numU << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You are missing a few header files or else this won't compile.

Comment: This: `c+= shift;   c = static_cast<char>(c+shift);` will shift twice. Also, your switch does nothing.

Comment: This is the only way I know of to ignore the case of "aeiou". If this doesn't work, then what should I do? @VladFeinstein

Comment: @ZhizhongLiu (1) this doesn't ignore anything, it literally does nothing. (2) why would you want to ignore `"aeiou"`?

Comment: I need to ignore the case of the five letters "aeiou" because I need to count the number of occurrentions of these five letters (both uppercase and lowercase) in the TXT text and output them.@VladFeinstein

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an answer to make the code readable.

`toupper(c)` will convert the character `c` to upper case; it will never be equal to `'a'`, `'e'`, etc. Use `'A'`.

You need to check for vowels in the `input`, so do your test before encoding/decoding. And increment the counters in the appropriate `case`:

```
while (inputFile.get(c)) {
    switch (toupper(c)) {
    case 'A':
        numA++;
        break;
    case 'E':
        numE++;
        break;
    case 'I':
        numI++;
        break;
    case 'O':
        numO++;
        break;
    case 'U':
        numU++;
        break;
    }

    c += shift;
    cout << c;
    // ...
}
```